# Confused about the values shown in circles (Brilliant.org)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

[image]

[image]

For the left side, I know it must be $2y-2$ because $y$ is being added with $y-2$.

But for the right side the solution is $2y-4$ or $4-2y?$ I don't know how this is occurring, and I'm completely stumped, I can see $y-4$.

$y-2+-2 = y-4$

But, where did the coefficient of $2$ come from?

Comment: The $\times$ means multiplication, not addition.  That is, you want to answer $(y-2)\times (-2)$.

Comment: But wouldn't that produce $y+4$?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this as well but that does not produce the options as shown.

Comment: No.  It would produce $-2y + 4$.  You should look up the "distributive property" if you need to learn/review it.

Comment: I was using copy paste and forgot to put in $-2$ sorry. But isn't that still not an option?

Comment: Since $4$ is positive? Or I'm guessing it's $4-2y$ right?